# Samba fails Achilles Level 2 tests

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, central-processing-unit, samba4, stress-testing

During certain Achilles tests, CPU consumption of Samba rises to 100%.

I am doing Achilles tests on a Linux-based server. I have noticed that during certain tests (and UDP port discovery), the temperature of the CPU cores surges to around 80-90 °C which causes the CPU clock to throttle and renders the server practically unresponsive.

Following closer investigations, we found out that there is a direct link between the rise of CPU consumption by a certain process and the CPU temperature. In our case, the concerned process is Samba

We are using samba4 in the full active directory mode.

Environment details:

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Samba version: 4.3.11

In our environment, there is a direct connection between the server running Samba and the test PC; no other element in the network.

As far as we understand, this looks like a DoS attack. Certain tests render the server completely unresponsive.

Is this a known issue? If yes, is there a fix for it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If your server cooling cannot cool down the temperature during 100% usage I would rather check the cooling and if a fan failed. Trying to make a process responsible is the wrong end to fix things here.

Comment: Well we have also contacted the server manufacturer regarding this issue. The purpose of my question was not to blame the process, in fact I would simply like to know why samba consumes 100% of my CPU under certain tests. It is definitely abnormal isn't it?

Comment: If you stress test samba then it is very likely that it will reach 100% CPU usage. Under normal circumstances it is abnormal, but that also depends on the amount of samba mounts, what the users do, network traffic etc.